# how to write retrofit dependency in this libs format

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, build.gradle, retrofit2

Not able to add this dependency in build.gradle
`com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0`
I don't know how to write dependencies in this new gradle version.
[Tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44rzN.jpg)
Not able to do this
`implementation(libs.com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it, By editing libs.versions.toml
[libs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqUfh.png)
Then I was able to use it.
[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMCVc.png)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first add the dependency to the version catalog (the `gradle/libs.versions.toml` file), as described in [Migrate your build to version catalogs](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs), after that you'll be able to use the `libs` notation. Note that you can still add the dependency bypassing the version catalog, although it's not recommended:

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
```

Comment: Ok Thanks , i will try.
I also figured out something. Can you please check and review it.

Comment: Yep, that follows my suggestion. Glad it worked for you!